# UIActivityViewController automatically closed

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm presenting activity controller on iPhone by this way:

```
let shareText = track.name
    let shareUrl = NSURL(string: "https://api.test.com/"
    let shareVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareText, shareUrl], applicationActivities: nil)
    self.presentViewController(shareVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have UITabbarC -> UINavigationC -> UIViewC -> presented modally UINavigationC -> UIViewC -> opening UIActivityViewC from here. It's opened without problems, but when I pressing on Email App, for example, it's showed near 0.5-1 second and automatically closed.

Does somebody know what is the reason and how to fix this?

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: @Viktor. Did you get any solution for it. am also in same issue

Comment: @AvijitNagare Just found my old project. I have solved it using this way - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36596736/4899912. Not sure if it still actual. Also can't check the reason, bcs project is deprecated for a long time and I need to update it or create new one for testing.

Comment: @Viktor. Issue with My Code was. There was too many timer set to repeats: true. When i make them "false" it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You must present the UIActivityViewController in your highest or last view controller. It can be for example a navigationController..

You haven't specified your project structure by you can try for example:

```
if let vc = self.parentViewController {
   let shareText = track.name
   let shareUrl = NSURL(string: "https://api.test.com/"
   let shareVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareText, shareUrl], applicationActivities: nil)
   shareVC.setValue(shareText, forKey: "subject")
   vc.presentViewController(shareVC, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```

If your problem persist, look also these lines if you testing it on iPad :

> When presenting the view controller, you must do so using the
>   appropriate means for the current device. On iPad, you must present
>   the view controller in a popover. On iPhone and iPod touch, you must
>   present it modally.

```
if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone {
        self.presentViewController(shareVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {            
        if activityViewController.respondsToSelector("popoverPresentationController") {
            activityViewController.popoverPresentationController!.barButtonItem = sender as? UIBarButtonItem
            self.presentViewController(shareVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
```

Try to make a test with:

```
let shareText: String! = "Hello"
let shareurl: NSURL! = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
```

( this test because I want to exclude any  troubles around your HTTPS url, utf8 encoding and some weirdness around shareText)

**To remember**:
According to Apple forum [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/93492#93492):

> The simulator doesn't support mail. You should likely try testing mail
>   functionality in a device.

**Update:**
To isolate the mail issue , try to use this class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func sendEmailButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
        }
    }

    func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property

        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["someone@somewhere.com"])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("Sending you an in-app e-mail...")
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Sending e-mail in-app is not so bad!", isHTML: false)

        return mailComposerVC
    }

    func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
        let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        sendMailErrorAlert.show()
    }

    // MARK: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate Method
    func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!) {
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

How to use for example:

```
var emailTitle = "Feedback"
var messageBody = "Feature request or bug report?"
var toRecipients = ["myuser@myemail.com", "my2user@gmail.com"]
var mc:MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()

mc.mailComposeDelegate = self

mc.setSubject(emailTitle)
mc.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)
mc.setToRecipients(toRecipients)
```

Some details and discussion [here](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/08/25/send-email-in-app-using-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-with-swift/)..

Comment: I've added some code, look now if you have an iPad (in your question you dont specify your device type)

Comment: Ok, seems your problem going around activityItems construction. Look now the code, i've added the subject, and a little request in bottom..

Comment: Still not working. But now I receiving error on simulator in case if open mail app: 'MailCOmpositionService quit unexpectedly' with description '*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffaa9f268e0'' in logs

Comment: Tested on device - same trouble. Not only with mail app. Also with messages. Only notes work correct

Comment: I've added a  swift class for mail composing just if you need to debug your issue

Answer (score 0):

My views structure is UITabbarC -> UINavigationC -> UIViewC1 -> presented modally UINavigationC -> UIViewC2

When I call UIActivityViewController from UIViewC2(which presented modally over UIViewC1) I had described issue.

But when I closed UIViewC2 before showing UIActivityViewController - it works

My solution:

Added underController variable to UIViewC2 and set it manually before UIVIewC2 presenting

```
let shareVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareText, shareUrl], applicationActivities: nil)

self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
    self.underController?.presentViewController(shareVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```